# Is there a way to use Bootstrap toast in Flask flashing natively?

Tags: flask, toast

I want to show toast messages using `flash()` method in Flask. I know that Bootstrap `alerts` work, so I used the same logic and replaced the code for `alerts` with `toasts`. But it does not seem to work for me.

app.py

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        flash('This is a demo message.')
        return render_template('home.html')
```

flash.html

```html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
    <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="me-auto">Message</strong>
            <small>11 mins ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

base.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>

<body>

    {% include 'flash.html' %}
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to know how can I achieve this natively in Flask. If not then I will need to explore [Flask-Toastr](https://github.com/wiltonsr/Flask-Toastr) (you can suggest alternatives in case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely achievable using the flash functionality in flask, and I wouldn't recommending using something like Flask-Toastr.

The flash functionality in flask can wrap any HTML.

The issue with your code is in your bootstrap/html, which you can test by removing all of the flash stuff and just having:

```
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
    <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="me-auto">Message</strong>
            <small>11 mins ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll see that the flash doesn't show there either. I suspect the issue is that you aren't initialising the toast using javascript as required. The docs for Bootstrap Toasts are here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/

I recommend getting it working in plain HTML and then wrapping it in the flash.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with this today and it took me a while to understand that this is not complex and anyone making it very complex is doing so unnecessarily.

In your base.html you probably have this jinja to handle flashes:

```
{# Application Flashes with Toasts 3.25.23 #}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
      {% include 'components/toasts.html' %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Next, you're going to want to include the html for the toasts themselves. In this case I did that in a separate HTML file called toasts.html, but you can also add this to your base.html:

```
<div class="toast-container position-fixed end-0 p-3 pt-0 toast-container-extra" id="toast-stack-container" style="top: 80px;">
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            {% if category == 'danger' %}
                  <div class="toast mt-0 border-danger" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-bs-autohide="true" data-stack-toast-category="error">
                    <div class="toast-header">
                      <i class="fa-light fa-circle-exclamation text-danger" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <strong class="me-auto text-black">Action Needed</strong>
                      <small>Just Now</small>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toast-body toast-message">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if category == 'info' %}
                  <div class="toast mt-0 border-danger" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-bs-autohide="true" data-stack-toast-category="error">
                    <div class="toast-header">
                      <i class="fa-light fa-circle-exclamation text-danger" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <strong class="me-auto text-black">Action Needed</strong>
                      <small>Just Now</small>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toast-body toast-message">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if category == 'success' %}
                  <div class="toast mt-0 border-success" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" data-stack-toast-category="info">
                    <div class="toast-header">
                      <i class="fa-light fa-check text-success" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <strong class="me-auto text-black">Success</strong>
                      <small>Just Now</small>
                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toast-body toast-message">
                    {{ message }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

The last thing you're going to want to do is add the javascript to show the toasts when things flash. You'll also need to import jquery or it won't work (this can be done before also). You can easily make this complicated so don't, just add it below your HTML.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.toast').toast('show');
    });
</script>
```

My approach includes flash categories and messages. You can remove those if you don't need them. Here is what the flash looks like in my view functions:

```
 flash(f'You are now signed in {user.user_name_field}', category='success')
```

That's it. Hopefully that was helpful!