# Flask flash - use bootstrap toast

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-5

I am using Boostrap-Flask (not Flask-Bootstrap) with Bootstrap 5.

When I save a form I can use Flash to display an alert using the Bootstrap-Flask macro render_messages

This works fine. However, I'd like to use a Toast rather than an Alert.

I tried doing this via Javascript rather than using flash. This triggers when I hit the submit button. But the toast flashes very fast due to the Flask page reloading on save, I only actually see it if I put an alert("saved") before it in my javascript which delays the page reload just long enough to see the toast flash up. So it is displaying but vanishes immediately on the page refresh. I don't understand why an alert can be sent and displayed but a toast cannot.

```
function validateForm() {
        let toastAlert = document.getElementById('toastAlert');
        let toastBody = document.getElementById('toastBody');
        let toasticon = document.getElementById('toasticon');
        let requested_by = document.forms["form"]["requested_by"].value;

      
        option = {"autohide": false};
        toasticon.classList = "h4 bi bi-check2-circle align-middle";
        toastAlert.classList = "toast align-items-center text-white bg-success border";
        toastBody.innerHTML = " Ticket Saved!";
        let toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastAlert, option);
        toast.show();
        return true;
     };
```

I have also tried this in my html page:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
    <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="me-auto">Message</strong>
            <small>11 mins ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

as per this SO answer [Is there a way to use Bootstrap toast in Flask flashing natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639448/is-there-a-way-to-use-bootstrap-toast-in-flask-flashing-natively)

But it does not work.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by putting the following code into an HTML file and importing this into my base.html

```
<!-- Begin alerts -->
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
{% if messages %}
{% for category, message in messages %}
<script>

    option = {"autohide": true, timeout:1500};

    toastAlert.classList = "toast align-items-center text-white bg-{{category}} border";
    toasticon.classList = "toast-icon-{{category}}"; <!-- defined in styles.css -->
    toastBody.innerHTML = "{{ message }}";
    let toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastAlert, option);
    toast.show();

 </script>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}

<!-- End alerts -->
```

I also have this in a separate HTML file that I import in my base.html

```
<!--    Toast Notification t-->
<div id="toast-pos" class="toast-container position-fixed top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x p-3" style="z-index: 1099">
<div id="toastAlert" class="toast align-items-center text-white bg-danger border" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="toast-body">
      <div class="hstack gap-3">
        <span id="toasticon" class="toast-icon-danger"></span>
        <span id="toastBody" class="ms-auto h5 text-center align-middle" >Hello, world! This is a toast message.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I created some css to change the icons depending on the Flash category:

```
.toast-icon-success::before {
    font-size: 3rem;
    content: "\F26A";
    font-family: 'bootstrap-icons';
}

.toast-icon-danger::before {
    font-size: 3rem;
    content: "\F336";
    font-family: 'bootstrap-icons';
}

.toast-icon-info::before {
    font-size: 3rem;
    content: "\F332";
    font-family: 'bootstrap-icons';
}

.toast-icon-warning {
    font-size: 3rem;
    content: "\F33A";
    font-family: 'bootstrap-icons';
}
```

I can now Flash messages from Flask and they are displayed as Bootstrap toasts.